# How to maintain webview urls for multiple tabs in android on press home button and come back on app

Tags: java, android, android-webview

how to maintain webview url for multiple tab when user press home button and come back on my app.

Now i can manage number of tabs but how to maintain url with them of webview.
when user come on app it's showing new page which is home page.
.
if you want i can explain more in detail.

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Here is my code.
In code you can see on create i can get number of tabs but how to maintain we bview url with them.

```
 @Override
    protected final void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tabSwitcher = (TabSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.tab_switcher);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(tabSwitcher, createWindowInsetsListener());
        tabSwitcher.setDecorator(new Decorator());
        tabSwitcher.addListener(this);
        tabSwitcher.showToolbars(true);
        tabSwitcher
                .setToolbarNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_box_white_24dp, createAddTabListener());
        tabSwitcher.inflateToolbarMenu(R.menu.tab_switcher, createToolbarMenuListener());
        tabSwitcher.getViewTreeObserver()
                .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(createTabSwitcherLayoutListener());

        for (int i = 0; i < TAB_COUNT; i++) {
            tabSwitcher.addTab(createTab(i));
        }


    }



 @NonNull
    private Tab createTab(final int index) {
        CharSequence title = getString(R.string.tab_title, index + 1);
        Tab tab = new Tab(title);
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putInt(VIEW_TYPE_EXTRA, index);
        tab.setParameters(parameters);
        return tab;
    }



  private class Decorator extends TabSwitcherDecorator {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View onInflateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater,
                                  @Nullable final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
            View view;


                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_edit_text, parent, false);


            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.tab);
            toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(createToolbarMenuListener());
            Menu menu = toolbar.getMenu();
            TabSwitcher.setupWithMenu(tabSwitcher, menu, createTabSwitcherButtonListener());
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowTab(@NonNull final Context context,
                              @NonNull final TabSwitcher tabSwitcher, @NonNull final View view,
                              @NonNull final Tab tab, final int index, final int viewType,
                              @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            TextView textView = findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            textView.setText(tab.getTitle());
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setVisibility(tabSwitcher.isSwitcherShown() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            Button bnt =  findViewById(R.id.button1);

            if (viewType != 0) {
                EditText editText = findViewById(android.R.id.edit);
                editText.requestFocus();
            }

            EditText editText = findViewById(android.R.id.edit);


            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText())) {

                bnt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

                {

                    WebView web1;
                    EditText editText = findViewById(android.R.id.edit);

                    public void onClick(final View view) {

                        String Address = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + editText.getText().toString();
                        web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

                        WebSettings webSetting = web1.getSettings();
                        webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                        webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                        web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                        web1.loadUrl(Address);

                    }


                });
            }else{

                WebView web1;
           ;
                web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                String webUrl = web1.getUrl();
                editText.setText(webUrl);
                WebSettings webSetting = web1.getSettings();
                webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                web1.loadUrl(webUrl);
            }
        }

public class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient
{



    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(android.R.id.edit);
        editText.setText(url);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }



}
```